# Why $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+k^3}\cos(kx)$ converge to a $\mathcal C^1(\mathbb R)\cap P(2\pi)$ function?

Tags: real-analysis

Why $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+k^3}\cos(kx)$$
converge to a $\mathcal C^1(\mathbb R)$ function that is $2\pi-$periodic ?

First of all, the series converge normally, and thus uniformly. So the limit is continuous. The derivative is $$-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k}{1+k^3}\sin(kx)$$

that is also normally convergent to a continuous function $g$.

Now, I guess that $g=f'$, but I'm not sure on how to justify it.

Comment: The formal derivative is a totally convergent series of continuous and $2\pi$-periodic functions, hence a continuous and $2\pi$-periodic function.

Answer (score 1):

The series of the derivates converges normally as well, as already noted. Thus, we can interchange integration and summation as follows:
\begin{align}
\int_0^t \sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{k}{1+k^3} \sin(kx) \, dx &=  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_0^t   \frac{k}{1+k^3} \sin(kx) \, dx \\
& = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^3+1} \cos(kt) -\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^3+1}.
\end{align}

By the fundamental theorem of calcalus we know that $g=f'$.